# Selenium.Unable to enter username and password for a website

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have two input fields username and password. I am unable to locate and enter the inputs using selenium. Login button click also fails.

Please find the HTML

```
    <div id="loginTable">
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="loginForm" method="POST" action="/cgi-bin/login">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>User name:</td><td colspan="2"><input name="LOGIN"></td></tr><tr>
  <td>Password:</td><td colspan="2"><input name="PWD" type="password"></td></tr><tr>
<td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Login</button></td></tr></tbody></table></form></div>
```

i have used below code lines,

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"loginTable\"]/form/table/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("test");
driver.findElement(By.name("LOGIN")).sendKeys("test");

WebElement userEntry=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("LOGIN")));
userEntry.sendKeys("Test");

None of them are working.

Login button also not working.
Please help me.

Comment: There is no input tag in the html code you have pasted. Is that the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your locator. You need something to identify the type of element you're looking for at the start (e.g. "//div[@id...." or "//*[@id...." if you want it as a wildcard) However you can simplify your locator to:

```
//input[@name='LOGIN']
```

Compound locators like the one you've attempted to use can be very brittle, as there are more elements from your code that could potentially change.

Comment: Thanks alot Smith. Can you please share full command. I have tried with //input[@name='LOGIN']. but it is not working. I am  a beginner in Selinium. Please share me full line of command.Thank you.